# "EROR GITBash" bash: syntax error near unexpected token "newline"

Tags: git, github, git-bash

```
Taufik Satria N@boxnug MINGW64 ~/UNSOED/vscode/Portofolio-Bootsrap5 (main)
$  git remote remove < https://github.com/taufiksatrian/taufiksatrian.git>

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
git remote remove https://github.com/taufiksatrian/taufiksatrian.git
```

Try just that. You have a new line before the address, and I don’t think the angle brackets should be there

Comment: after adding code formatting, I see that there was no newline.  So I guess the angle bracket were the problem?